# Why does Broken Age crash on launch?

Tags: broken-age

Broken Age opens for a few moments; then, before the end of the Double Fine logo, it gives me a "This program has stopped responding" message.  Any ideas?

Comment: Posting this because I ran into it about five minutes after install.  Along with the solution in my case. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be many things, but one thing to check: your graphics card is actually turned on.

My system has [NVIDIA Optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html); however, brand new games are often not on its list, so the video card doesn't activate.

To manually add a new game to its list (At least on my machine that is running Windows 7):

- Make sure the machine is plugged in
- Search for and open "NVIDIA Control Panel" (You can also right click the desktop to get to it)
- In the treeview on the left, choose 3D Settings -> Manage 3D settings.  If this option doesn't appear you may not have plugged in the machine.  If it still doesn't appear, try rebooting.
- Under "I would like to use the following 3D settings", switch to the "Program Settings" tab
- Click "Add"
- Navigate to the location of the new game.  For Broken Age on Steam, my machine put it into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Broken Age`; select the game `.exe` and click "Open"
- Check the game now appears in the program list and is currently selected
- From the dropdown just below the program list, switch it to "High performance NVIDIA processor".

If you don't have Optimus on your machine, other suggestions: Check all pre-requisites, e.g. video card drivers, DirectX, etc, are up to date...

Answer (score 1):

It has some bug on "in-Game" Hud of Steam.
On Steam Library, secondary-button click on Broken Age, Properties, and on General Tab uncheck the "Enable Steam Community In-Game" option.

Comment: Suspected this myself, and it works perfectly.